# How to keep track of nesting information on iterative (non-recursive) function

Tags: algorithm, parsing, recursion, data-structures, stack

Say I have a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) that defines a bunch of nested rules.

```
Expr    ← Sum
Sum     ← Product (('+' / '-') Product)*
Product ← Value (('*' / '/') Value)*
Value   ← [0-9]+ / '(' Expr ')'
```

Say I am right ● here on the second `Value` in the process:

```
Expr    ← Sum
Sum     ← Product (('+' / '-') Product)*
Product ← Value (('*' / '/') ●)*
Value   ← [0-9]+ / '(' Expr ')'
```

That would mean that I am somewhere in here in a nesting level let's say:

```
Expr
  Sum
    |Product
     +
     Product
    |Product
     -
     Product
       |Value
        *
        Value
       |Value
        *
        ●
```

When parsing with recursive descent, it is recursive so when `Value` returns, we get back to the "sequence" `*` parsing node, which then returns to the `Product` node, which returns to the product sequence node, etc. So it's easy to build up the parsing tree.

But let's say that you want to do this using an [iterative stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314005/how-to-convert-bottom-up-recursive-algorithm-to-iterative-stack-in-javascript). The question is, how to keep track of the nesting information so that you can say in your code (eventually):

```
function handleValue(state, string) {
  // ...
}

function handleValueSequence(state, string) {
  if (state.startedValueSequenceEarlier) {
    wrapItUp(new ValueSequence(state.values))
  }
}

function handleProduct(state, string) {
  // ...
}

function handleProductSequence(state, string) {
  if (state.startedProductSequenceEarlier) {
    wrapItUp(new ProductSequence(state.products))
  }
}
```

The tricky part is, this can be arbitrarily nested, so you might have:

```
Product
  Value
    Product
      Value
        Product
          ...
```

So if your function like `handleProductSequence` doesn't have any context other than the function's arguments, I can't tell how it should figure out how to "wrapItUp" and finally create that `ProductSequence` object. In that `state` object I added, I am trying to think of ways of adding a `state.stack` property or something, but I'm not sure what would go in there. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack has to contain "where you are" in the control flow. In a recursive descent parser, that will be effectively the same as where you are in the parse, so you could write a generalised LL parser in this fashion. Personally, I'd probably represent a production as an object with a list of tokens and a handler function. (Plus some extension for EBNF operators like `*`.) A state would then be a production, a position in the production, and a list of already matched values.

But it's hard to see a good reason to do that when LR parser generators already exist, using essentially this representation, and they can handle many more grammars.