# Performance of built-in stack vs. manually implemented function call stack

Tags: function, stack, iteration

I have been wondering how to convert recursive functions to iterative ones using a stack, such as here:

[How to convert bottom-up recursive algorithm to iterative stack in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314005/how-to-convert-bottom-up-recursive-algorithm-to-iterative-stack-in-javascript)

I am wondering though if there is any advantage of doing so from a performance perspective. It seems on one-hand that it allows for very large stack size, so you avoid the "max stack size exceeded" error in some languages, but that is not a performance problem. On the other hand it seems that perhaps the stack is using more optimized code such as the built-in hardware stack or something along those lines, so it could have significant losses in switching to an iterative version of a function.

Comment: By performance do you mean speed? If that's the case I'd recommend some sort of timer depending on the language to compare the two functions, recuresive vs. iterative

Comment: It really depends. While you get the advantage of hardware-managed stacks, you also get the overhead of function calls (parameter passing, saving and restoring registers), and the frame is usually larger than what you would have saved manually, so you are more likely to run out of L1 cache. Plus you will almost certainly overflow the return address predictor. The only way to know which way the balance swings is to try it both ways and measure.

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you that was all I was looking for.